# How to extrude inwards without leaving faces?

Tags: extrude

Here is the image to explain what i want

[image]

left box shows how i have set loopcuts (green is the face that i am extruding and moving). Middle one is what i want to get. The right is the issue with blender. the red faces will remain. (i have removed doubles on those faces) So is it possible to extrude inwards so that you dont have those faces hanging ? I know i could just delete those faces and thats it. but if you have lot of elements with similar idea it will get time consuming.  Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Follow these steps

1) Go on Face select

[image]

2) Select the faces you want to "block" and click on Offset Edge slide

[image]

In this way these 2 faces will be indipendent from the others

3) **Move** your middle face in the position you prefer. **Remember: move it, not extrude.**

[image]

4) Select all your mesh and press <kbd>w</kbd> --> **Remove doubles**

Comment: Glad to help! Good night ;)

Comment: That's why I love this site. No matter how long you learn Blender there are still some cool tricks you haven't discovered by yourself. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Glad to help mate! I love this feature too ^^

Comment: Also, extruding in vertex select mode works without leaving the unwanted faces.

Comment: I have a 'little black book' filled with gems picked up from this site.  This ans has just been added to it...  My thanks to @Fuboski, along with countless others.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by checking the box on the *Dissolve Orthogonal Edges* option on bottom left box *Extrude Region and Move*.
[image: Extrude Region and Move box]

Duplicated cubes, extruded, on the left with option checked, right one without
[image: Duplicated cubes, extruded, on the left with option checked, right one without]