# What is the fastest way to do a cut extrude / inward extrude?

Tags: modeling, mesh, extrude

Let's say after a knife project I have a nice region that I want to extrude. Extruding outwards along the normal works fine. Extruding inwards along -Z however does not work the way I want it to.
Starting geometry with selection to be extruded inward:
[image: 1]

Dragging this down generates correct faces in the interior but also zero volume regions at the exterior:
[image: 2]

Instead, I am looking for a final mesh without these exterior slivers. Similar to ZBrush's QMesh or Solidworks Extrude Cut:
[image: 3]

This is obviously a simplified example where I can delete offending faces one at a time. What is the best workflow to either avoid these faces or quickly select them all?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8639/599

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50780/how-to-extrude-inwards-without-leaving-faces (although I couldn't achieve that behaviour, rather than with simple [filling face](http://i.imgur.com/UC18p9L.gif))

Answer (score 5):

Extrude the face you don't want to move then <kbd>RMB</kbd> to leave the duplicated edges in place.  Now select the face you want to move and you get the behaviour you want, except there is an edge loop that has been left behind.  Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> click to convert the selection to vertices, then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>RMB</kbd> click the edge loop.  Translate the selection and you're done.

[image]

Comment: The second part is giving me problems. I did the in-place extrude, and I can move the corner face just fine leaving the diagonal loop as you mentioned. I did Ctrl-Tab to convert to Vertex select mode, but where do I Shift-Alt-RMB click? That part is not working for me.

Comment: Pressing H, hiding the extrusion and then selecting the leftover verts should work, too.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Boolean Modifier, it's like subtracting an object shape from another one.