# Extrude inward without leaving faces in blender 2.82?

Tags: extrude

I want to extrude inwards without leaving faces [image]

Comment: you're talking about Destructive Extrude, I'm not sure it's already implemented but you can find some addons that do it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H7IgdS6j9js  https://www.mediafire.com/file/m3kgqwi35p49h2s/Destructive-Extrude.py/file

Comment: Its a new feature for the 2.90 Blender release. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FlhAjyLnvrY&feature=emb_logo .  2.90 alpha version can be downloaded from here ... https://builder.blender.org/download/

Comment: [This question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51729/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-do-a-cut-extrude-inward-extrude)  and [this one also](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50780/how-to-extrude-inwards-without-leaving-faces)  both show different solutions.