# How do you do an intrude instead of extrude?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

[image]

Lets say I want to decrease the height of the back of the chair, or all of its legs, how is the easier way to do it? I mean without cutting each of them into two pieces and deleting the remaining parts.

If I choose all the bottom faces of the legs, press <kbd>E</kbd> , and then drag up, it will create hollow spaces. Same thing probably applied for the back of the chair.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51729/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-do-a-cut-extrude-inward-extrude https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50780/how-to-extrude-inwards-without-leaving-faces https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8639/intrude-faces-instead-of-extruding

Comment: it's not clear what you mean by intrude, could you please show what you mean with a second picture? There's a new tool called Extrude Manifold (Alt E) but I'm not sure it's what you're looking for

Comment: @moonboots if its not clear then read the entirety of the post, if its not clear by second picture then read the whole thing

Comment: I thought you wanted something else than just move down the faces, "intrude" sounds like the opposite of "extrude", and in Blender extrude is this particular operation than you get pressing E, there's no "intrusion" per se, except lately with alt E > Extrude Manifold, but I was not sure this is what you wanted and actually it was not  ;)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to simply just grab all the faces on the bottom of the chair, press <kbd>G</kbd> to grab them, and press <kbd>Z</kbd> afterwards to pull the faces only vertically. This isn't intruding, but just moving faces. Simply put, drag the faces up *without* pressing <kbd>E</kbd>, in the case of the chair legs. I hope this answers your question!

On another note...
if you press <kbd>I</kbd>, then inset faces, and *then* extrude, moving up into the mesh, it will create a hollow space with depth, rather than just 4 faces with no cap. This second response probably doesn't answer your question, but this is probably what 'Intrude' means in Blender.

Comment: yeah, it works, thanks

Comment: sorry, it doesnt work in this version of my chair https://i.imgur.com/gV1I6f8.png  In this, using G + Z  creates hollow spaces like with E.

Comment: You have already extruded, meaning that there are new vertices that are being grabbed. Grab the face, press 'x' and click on 'delete faces'. Depending on how many times you extruded, you need to repeat this process until there isn't a face on the bottom of the chair. then grab the edges around the bottom of the chair, and press 'F' to fill. This will make a new face, and grab that face and move it

Comment: Sorry I dont really understand here. And you probably mixed up "select" with "grab" there in your comment